# partial view in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am new to Jquery mobile and asp.net mvc4. In my application I have divided my page into three blocks(ui-block-a,ui-block-b,ui-block-c).These three blocks are in shared folder(_Layout.cshtml). Left side and right side blocks are partially viewed. In the middle block is normally viewed. When I perform any modification the partial view is also refershing.I want to load my partial view on my first time loading only. If I do any change on middle block the partial views should not be affected. please help how can 
I do this?

Answer (score 0):

`Partial view` doesn't mean it would be partially updated. It's just a small chunk of ui code wich is suitable to be grouped into a separated file for reuse.

you'll need to implement ajax functions into **middle block** when updating.

[jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

would be the api you can refer to.